# How does export work in plotly DataTable?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm working on an app in python that displays data in a plotly DataTable (see https://dash.plot.ly/datatable). In multiple places, the documentation refers to an export or copy/paste functionality that is supposed to be included in the DataTable. But I can't find any documentation how the user interface for this might work. 
If I have a DataTable like this:

```
   dash_table.DataTable(
        id='rating-summary-table',
        data=df_summary.to_dict('records)'),
        columns=columns,
        style_cell_conditional=[
            {'if': dict(column_id='Name'), 'textAlign': 'left'},
        ],
    )
```

it is displayed in the web UI, but how do I invoke the copy/paste feature? It should simply copy all data displayed (with headers) on the clipboard to be pasted into an Excel spreadsheet.
I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Highlight the data inside the table and press Strg+C?

Comment: If you want users to download the raw data, refer to this thread: https://community.plot.ly/t/download-raw-data/4700/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the component **component_property** derived_virtual_data in a callback, and write something like :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(virtual_data)
```

example

```
@app.callback(
    Output('saved-results', 'children'),
    [Input('save-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State(component_id='rating-summary-table', component_property="derived_virtual_data")],
)
def save_results(n_clicks, virtual_data):
    if n_clicks is not None:
        df = pd.DataFrame(virtual_data)
        df.rename(columns={v: k for k, v in col_dict.items()}, inplace=True)
        filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '_results.csv'
        saved_results.append(filename)
        df.to_csv(RESULTS_DIRECTORY + filename,
                  encoding='utf-8',
                  index=False,
                  sep=';')
        return files_list
    else:
        return [html.Li("Dataframe saved")]
```

Comment: +1 currently the best way to export data from DataTable is to create your own callback. This provides you with more flexibility as the name the file, do further post-processing, etc. Thank you for this answer.